# Fastlane failed while uploading to TestFlight

Tags: ios, app-store, archive, testflight, fastlane

I have a simple `fastlane` command like below.

```
  desc "Push a new beta build to TestFlight"
  lane :beta do
    build_app(workspace: "Project.xcworkspace", scheme: "Project")
    upload_to_testflight
  end
```

It finished the archive successfully. But crashed during the upload process with the following log:

```
[11:24:38]: ▸ ** ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED **
[11:24:38]: 
[11:24:38]: ⬆️  Check out the few lines of raw `xcodebuild` output above for potential hints on how to solve this error
[11:24:38]:   For the complete and more detailed error log, check the full log at:
[11:24:38]:   /Users/user/Library/Logs/gym/project.log
[11:24:38]: 
[11:24:38]: Looks like fastlane ran into a build/archive error with your project
[11:24:38]: It's hard to tell what's causing the error, so we wrote some guides on how
[11:24:38]: to troubleshoot build and signing issues: https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/getting-started/
[11:24:38]: Before submitting an issue on GitHub, please follow the guide above and make
[11:24:38]: sure your project is set up correctly.
[11:24:38]: fastlane uses `xcodebuild` commands to generate your binary, you can see the
[11:24:38]: the full commands printed out in yellow in the above log.
[11:24:38]: Make sure to inspect the output above, as usually you'll find more error information there
[11:24:38]: 
[11:24:38]: Looks like no provisioning profile mapping was provided
[11:24:38]: Please check the complete output, in particular the very top
[11:24:38]: and see if you can find more information. You can also run fastlane
[11:24:38]: with the `--verbose` flag.
[11:24:38]: Alternatively you can provide the provisioning profile mapping manually
[11:24:38]: https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/xcode-project/#xcode-9-and-up
+------------------+-----------+
|         Lane Context         |
+------------------+-----------+
| DEFAULT_PLATFORM | ios       |
| PLATFORM_NAME    | ios       |
| LANE_NAME        | ios tests |
| BUILD_NUMBER     | 4         |
+------------------+-----------+
[11:24:38]: Error packaging up the application

+------+------------------------+-------------+
|              fastlane summary               |
+------+------------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                 | Time (in s) |
+------+------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform       | 0           |
| 2    | increment_build_number | 2           |
|    | build_app              | 742         |
+------+------------------------+-------------+

[11:24:38]: fastlane finished with errors

[!] Error packaging up the application
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that when I try to upload the app manually, Xcode throws an exception related to permissions. My current profile has a `developer` role, and validating and uploading to TestFlight requires an `admin` role. I changed the profile and Fastlane is successfully finished.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue when trying to signe iOs app with fastlane tool, and if you check above there should be ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED message in the CLI.
And if you scroll up, above the ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED message you could find the table with the path to your archives

For example mine was:

/Users/********/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/****-**-**

Where:

******** = Username

****-**-** = Date

So, just open these resulting archives with xCode and you could validate and upload them to AppStoreConnect.
Thank you.